# data can't be queried out when running the Ignite streamer word count example

Tags: ignite

I am following the steps in https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/streaming-example. to explore the Ignite streaming word count example. When I run the query, no data is queried out.
Following is my code:

```
public class CacheConfig {

    public static CacheConfiguration<String, Long> createWordCache() {
        CacheConfiguration<String, Long> cfg = new CacheConfiguration<String, Long>("words");
        cfg.setIndexedTypes(String.class, Long.class);
        return cfg;
    }
}


public class WorkStreamIntoCache {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);
        String configPath = "D:/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml";
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configPath);
        IgniteCache<String, Long> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CacheConfig.createWordCache());

        IgniteDataStreamer<String, Long> streamer = ignite.dataStreamer(cache.getName());

        streamer.allowOverwrite(true);


        streamer.receiver(StreamTransformer.from(new CacheEntryProcessor<String, Long, Object>() {

            public Object process(MutableEntry<String, Long> mutableEntry, Object... objects) throws EntryProcessorException {
                Long preValue = mutableEntry.getValue();
                if (preValue == null) {
                    mutableEntry.setValue(1L);
                } else {
                    mutableEntry.setValue(preValue + 1);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }));


        while (true) {
            InputStream in = WorkStreamIntoCache.class.getResourceAsStream("/words.txt");
            List<String> lines = IOUtils.readAsLines(in);
            for (String line : lines) {
                String[] words = line.split(" ");
                for (String word : words) {
                    word = word.trim();
                    if (word != null && word.length() > 0) {
                        streamer.addData(word, 1L);
                        System.out.println(word + " is writing to the cache @" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd HHmmss").format(new Date()));
                    }
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(120 * 1000);
        }

    }
}

public class QueryWords {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Ignition.setClientMode(true);

        String configPath = "D:/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml";
        Ignite ignite = Ignition.start(configPath);
        IgniteCache<String, Long> cache = ignite.getOrCreateCache(CacheConfig.createWordCache());

        SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery("select * from Long");

        while (true) {
            List<List<?>> data = cache.query(sql).getAll();
            if (data == null || data.size() <= 0) {
                System.out.println("No data is found in the cache");
            }
            for (List<?> datum : data) {
                for (Object record : datum) {
                    System.out.println("record: " + record);
                }
            }
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}
```

The steps that run the example:

1. First I start the ignite server using `bin/ignite.bat  D:/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml`
2. Then in the IDEA ide, I run the WorkStreamIntoCache program, I can see the log that the words are writing to the cache
3. When I run the QueryWords , I can't query out the data, only `No data is found in the cache`is found in the console.

Could some help where the problem is? Thanks!

Comment: Could someone take a look at this question? Thanks.

Comment: Did you share full code? It looks like cache was destroyed or cache entries were expired and the you run data querying.

Comment: Yes, this is all the code. I run these two main classes in IDE with ignite started in client mode, and start ignite server locally with bin/ignite.bat  D:/apache-ignite-fabric-1.7.0-bin/config/default-config.xml.  I will spend more time on this, Thanks @a_gura

Comment: Can you create a small GitHub project so that I or someone else can easily run it and reproduce the behavior? This way it will be much easier to tell what you're doing wrong.